# How to toggle the visibility of multiple elements based of dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have the following HTML Elements:

```
#categoryid is a dropdown/select
#addFoo is a button
#removeFoo is button
#Foo is a div
#Bar is a div
```

I'm using the following script to change the visibility of these elements based on what's selected on the dropdown:

```
$('#categoryid').change(function () {
    var category = $(this).val();
    if (category === 'Foo') {
        $('#addFoo').removeClass('invisible');
        $('#removeFoo').removeClass('invisible');
        $('#Foo').removeClass('invisible');
    }
    else if (category === 'Bar') {
        $('#Bar').removeClass('invisible');
    }

    if (category !== 'Foo') {
        $('#addFoo').addClass('invisible');
        $('#removeFoo').addClass('invisible');
        $('#Foo').addClass('invisible');
    }

    if (category !== 'Bar') {
        $('#Bar').addClass('invisible');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.invisible {
   display:none;
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Next time, It'd be great if you post sample `HTML` rather than listing the type of elements... :)

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm curious how [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) could be used to improve this piece of code...

Comment: @TJ Maybe http://jsfiddle.net/ms0s1uo9/

Comment: @A.Wolff - you saved me from a sea of if-thens. You should make your comment an answer. Though I do have one question. What exactly does the second `.change()` do?

Comment: @A.Wolff That's cool... I haven't noticed the `switch` option till now... thanks!

Comment: @dotnetN00b Just to trigger change event once event handler bound. BTW, sorry quite busy right now, no time to write a 'correct' answer, you could still write yourself a descriptive answer and accept it to mark as resolved your question

Comment: @A.Wolff - Well your comments and jsfiddle were the correct answers. So whenever you have time, feel free to just copy and paste :) In any case, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a common class name `foo` (*or a `data-` attribute, whichever you prefer*) for those `Foo` elements:

```js
$('#categoryid').change(function () {
    if (this.value === 'Foo') {
        $('.foo').removeClass('invisible');
        $('#Bar').addClass('invisible');
    } else if (this.value === 'Bar') {
        $('#Bar').removeClass('invisible');
        $('.foo').addClass('invisible');
    }
}).trigger("change"); // for demo purpose
```

```css
.invisible {
    display:none;
}

div { /*for demo purpose*/
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categoryid">
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<div id="Foo" class="foo">Foo!</div>
<div id="Bar">Bar!</div>
<button id="addFoo" class="foo">add Foo!</button>
<button id="removeFoo" class="foo">remove Foo!</button>
```

---

Or if you must use those `id`'s, you can use [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like:

```js
$('#categoryid').change(function () {
    if (this.value === 'Foo') {
        $('[id*="Foo"]').removeClass('invisible');
        $('#Bar').addClass('invisible');
    } else if (this.value === 'Bar') {
        $('#Bar').removeClass('invisible');
        $('[id*="Foo"]').addClass('invisible');
    }
}).trigger("change"); // for demo purpose
```

```css
.invisible {
    display:none;
}

div { /*for demo purpose*/
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categoryid">
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<div id="Foo"></div>
<div id="Bar"></div>
<button id="addFoo">add Foo!</button>
<button id="removeFoo">remove Foo!</button>
```

---

**Update**

Even better, As [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) mentioned in comments, you can pass a condition that returns `true/false` which decides whether to add or remove the class respectively, as second argument to [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

```js
$('#categoryid').change(function () {
   $('.foo').toggleClass('invisible', this.value !== 'Foo');
   $('#Bar').toggleClass('invisible', this.value !== 'Bar');
}).trigger("change"); // for demo purpose
```

```css
.invisible {
    display:none;
}

div { /* for demo purpose */
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categoryid">
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<div id="Foo" class="foo">Foo!</div>
<div id="Bar">Bar!</div>
<button id="addFoo" class="foo">add Foo!</button>
<button id="removeFoo" class="foo">remove Foo!</button>
```

---

Side note: As others suggested you can use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) methods, but i'm assuming There is be  reason you're  using css classes - Like the injected inline styles having higher specificity than other class definitions...

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Use jquery [.hide()](http://gyazo.com/91ef84c06b057d00ec420dafeba3c097) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use `show()`, `hide()`, `slideUp()`, `slideDown()` methods present in jQuery:

```
$('#divid').show();
```